# Icons too big in Stepper

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, stepper

When you create steps in a `Stepper` with a `state` other than `indexed` or `disabled`, the icon reaches the edge of the circle, which looks "clunky".

This has been raised as issue [#16920](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16920) on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icons honour the sizing from the `iconTheme` property in the theme. As a workaround, you could override this in the `MaterialApp.theme` property, but that would affect all icons that also use the same theme, so you can wrap your `Stepper` in a `Theme` widget and override the `size` on the `iconTheme`:

`var theme = Theme.of(context);
Theme(
  data: theme.copyWith(iconTheme: theme.iconTheme.copyWith(size: 18.0),
  child: Stepper(…)
),`